# Emulate Python HTTP request using JS Fetch

Tags: javascript, python, http, python-requests, fetch

I can successfully do a simple HTTP request using python requests:

```
def renew_token():
    """
    Send a request to renew the login token
    """
    url = url
    fields = {
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password"
        }
    r = requests.post(url, data=fields)
    print(r)
```

I am trying to do the exact same request using javascript fetch, but with no luck.

```
async function renewToken(url = '', fields = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST'
      data: JSON.stringify(fields),
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache', 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    });
    return await response.json();
  }

  renewToken('url', { username: 'username', password: 'password' })
  .then((data) => {
  console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
  });
```

The error I get back is :

```
{ data: null,
  message: 'No username or password provided',
  status: 'api-error' }
```

which implies there is something wrong with the content type. I've tried changing the `content-type` to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', but I get the same error.

What am I missing to emulate the python request using fetch?

Answer (score 0):

Had to use form data , not sent data in body:

```
async function renewToken(url = '', fields = {}) {
            const response = await fetch(url, {
              method: 'POST', //
              body: 'username=username&password=password',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              },
            });
            return await response.json(); 
          }
```